# How to get src info from the html text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the src info from the html data using python beautifulsoup
content contains the complete html info. from that i would like to get the src info of the image. i tried the below code.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
for table in soup.findAll('table', {'class':'table_x_write'} ):
    links=table.findAll('img',{'id':'imgsglx2'})            
    print links
```

above code prints 
**[]**

from this how to get the src info

please help me on this issue

Comment: Printed data is                                                                                  [<img id="imgsglx2" onerror="this.alt='not select the picture or pictures cannot be displayed'" src="http://114.255.167.200:8092/cidasEN/extend/sglx_images/UTYP/221.jpg" style=" border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;height:110px;width:110px; "/>]

Comment: Looks right, if it prints something it means it got into the loop. But you probably missed something with the id

Comment: You need to post some html code that contains the `src` attribute.

Comment: @ettanany       html code is      [<img id="imgsglx2" onerror="this.alt='not select the picture or pictures cannot be displayed'" src="114.255.167.200:8092/cidasEN/extend/sglx_images/UTYP/…; style=" border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;height:110px;width:110px; "/>]